# Invalid authorization code when trying to get access token in spotipy

Tags: spotify

I am trying to authenticate my python app to a specific user using spotipy.  I have done this before with a few other users with no problems.  This user however each time I try I keep getting '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}'

I have also tried manually a couple different ways including curl:

> curl -H "Authorization: Basic OTQxNDliNjI3...WRhMzk5YTY2ZTliZWY=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=AQByvdq4Vr9-L_ZLrySeTOx...pm1vmb8vwGe2GUXcmTY#*=* -d redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fcallback https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}

I have tried both putting the client_code and client_secret in the header (as shown above) and in the post body both with the same error

keep in mind I am using the exact code I get from my callback url as soon as I can (cut and paste) and like I said before, this method has worked with other users with no problems.  Can anyone think of anything else I can try?

Comment: After trial and error I discovered that apparently the "#" and everything after it is NOT part of the code.  Spotipy doesn't properly parse this and my cut and paste didn't either.  When trying the code without the "#" it worked just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotipy currently has a bug where it doesn't correctly parse out the code from a given redirect_uri if that uri contains a trailing "#" segment.  When spotipy propmts for you to paste in the redirect_uri do so by copying the uri without including the "#" and everything following it